# How can i use open a new tab to access data or alert?

Tags: onload, tampermonkey

My script is based on Tampermonkey,However, the following code nothing happened after i create a new tab to access something even alert.

```
(function() {

    var url = "https://pad.skyozora.com/";
    var Tab = window.open(url);

    Tab.onload = function () {
        alert('a');
    };

})();
```

after the script create new tab , there will not have alert there.
How to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Modern Chrome doesn't display alerts in inactive windows.

Comment: but i even can't display console.log or access dom data.

Comment: Yep, that's because that URL is cross-origin: you'll need to add `@match` rule to your userscript so it'll run in that new tab and its instance will be able to do things in that tab including `alert`.